# How to index into SortedSet

Tags: julia

I am looking for a function to access the Nth element from the SortedSet.  I am having trouble understanding what the purpose of a sorted set is if you can't access by sort order.

```
using DataStructures

S = SortedSet()

S[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically different data collections are designed with different performance assumptions. `SortedSet` is designed so that in general you can expect that operations take `O(log(n))` time (this includes insertion, deletion, etc.). For iteration a single iteration also has the same time complexity, but if you iterate all elements of the set the amortized time complexity is `O(1)`.

All this is explained in https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/stable/sorted_containers/.

However, the downside of this is that the data structure used is not designed for `O(1)` indexing. AFAICT the use case for getting data from `SortedSet` is iteration over all its elements (in sorted order).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:  use the `collect` function:

```
julia> a = SortedSet([4,2,7,1,0])
SortedSet{Int64, Base.Order.ForwardOrdering} with 5 elements:
  0
  1
  2
  4
  7


julia> collect(a)[3]
2
```

You probably know this, and so are actually commenting on the potential loss of efficiency in having to convert the SortedSet in order to index into it. If it is such efficiency you want, then,  depending on your use case, if you have a sparse vector and know approximately what it will have as its maximum value, you can use a BitArray:

```
maxsize = 10000000
bitarray = falses(maxsize)

# now add to the set

for i in rand(1:maxsize, 10000)
    bitarray[i] = true
end

# extract the vector and index to get its 100th element:

values = [i for i in eachindex(bitarray) if bitarray[i]]

values[100]
```

For large sets with many added numbers, this is much more performant than a Set or a SortedSet.